# Who accepts Moneybookers/NETELLER?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Because I don't have any rep. and the chargeback issue, no one will buy my Moneybookers(USD) or NETELLER(USD). Is there an exchange that will?

Comment: Buying bitcoins with a reversible payment method like PayPal, MoneyBookers, NeTeller, etc, is always going to be difficult.  Cashing out to those methods is much easier though, with a half dozen methods: http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins):

- [VirVox](https://www.virwox.com/) accepts NETELLER and Moneybookers
- [Bitcoin.de](https://www.bitcoin.de) accepts Moneybookers

You could always approach high-rep users and ask them to do exchange with you at some rate favourable to them, and also letting them send you Bitcoins only after some time after which chargeback would be impossible. This way you risk little (high-rep users can generally be trusted), and you will get your positive reputation started.

Comment: VirVox seems to be down and Bitcoin.de is an exchange

Comment: @abrkn From the question: "Is there an exchange that will?", both of them are exchanges. VirVox appears to be up at least for me. You can always try doj.me website to verify if a webpage is down or not.

Comment: VirWox (note the W) ended support for Neteller on 2014-03-06.

Answer (score 0):

The only current option I could find so far is via LocalBitcoins.com (https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/neteller/).

The exchanges listed on the [official wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins) ([VirWox](https://www.virwox.com/), [mercaBit.eu](http://mercabit.eu/) and [rugatu.com](http://www.rugatu.com/)) that are noted to support Neteller are all down or ended their Neteller support.